# Angularjs costum filter does not trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

i have the following filter:

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('app')
    .filter('fromNow', function() {
        return function(date) {
          return moment(date).fromNow();
        }
    });
```

which i am trying to use here:

```
    <div class="streamline b-l m-b" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    <div class="sl-item b-{{activity.module.module_type.color.substr(activity.module.module_type.color.indexOf('-')+1,activity.module.module_type.color.length )}} b-l" ng-repeat="activity in activities">
        <div class="m-l">
            <div class="text-muted">{{activity.timestamp | filter:fromNow}}</div>
            <p>{{activity.module.name}}: {{activity.module.module_type_id == 1 ? 'Gennemført' : activity.score}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

however nothing is triggered..

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter` is already an Angular filter.  May be confusing since it's named `filter`, [but yes, there is a `filter` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

You just want to use your own named filter: `{{activity.timestamp | fromNow}}`

[More information on the syntax for using filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Comment: Confusing ive always thought you have to initilize the filter object but thank you it works like a charm!